# Why age is not displaying here in this program?

Tags: java

I am beginner and learning Java programming language from the last 3 days. Here, 3 instance variables are there and finally I am getting student record details except student's age. I am getting as '0' What mistake I have done here?? I am sorry for this kinda silly question.

```
public class Student{ // created class
String studentName; // DataMember or Instance variable
int age;
int rollNo;
// creating insertRecord method
void insertRecord(int age,String name,int rollno){ 
age=age;
studentName=name;
rollNo=rollno;  
}
void displayRecord(){
System.out.println(age+""+studentName+""+rollNo);
}
public static void main(String[] args){ // main method
Student s1=new Student(); // creating object
Student s2=new Student(); // creating object

s1.insertRecord(23,"Maida",101);
s2.insertRecord(24,"Wheet",102);
s1.displayRecord();
s2.displayRecord();

}
}
```

Output is,

```
0Maida101
0Wheet102
```

Correct code:

```
public class Student{ // created class
int age;
String studentName; // DataMember or Instance variable
int rollNo;

public Student(int age,String name,int rollno){ // creating constructor
this.age=age;
this.studentName=name;
this.rollNo=rollno;  
}

public String toString(){
System.out.println(age+""+studentName+""+rollNo);
return studentName;
}
public static void main(String[] args){ // main method
Student s1=new Student(23,"Maida",101); // creating object
Student s2=new Student(24,"Wheet",102); // creating object

s1.toString();
s2.toString();

}
}


Output is,
23Maida101
24Wheet102
```

Comment: You need to learn how to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
public class Student{ // created class
String studentName; // DataMember or Instance variable
int age;
int rollNo;
// creating insertRecord method
void insertRecord(int age,String name,int rollno){ 
this.age=age;
studentName=name;
rollNo=rollno;  
}
void displayRecord(){
System.out.println(age+""+studentName+""+rollNo);
}
public static void main(String[] args){ // main method
Student s1=new Student(); // creating object
Student s2=new Student(); // creating object

s1.insertRecord(23,"Meena",101);
s2.insertRecord(24,"Nisha",102);
s1.displayRecord();
s2.displayRecord();

}
}
```

**output**

```
23Meena101
24Nisha102
```

Comment: @MeenaRengarajan if instance variables and method arguements are same then use this keyoword.If confusing then better keep different names

Answer (score 7):

Assign age to the instance variable

```
this.age=age;
```

Otherwise you just assign the age parameter to the age parameter.
That has no effect.

Comment: +1, also insertRecord should be converted to a constructor and displayRecord should become the toString.